# How to set sort value in ngx-datatable dynamically?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using a ngx-datatable in my angular app, and i use sort property of this data table,
my datatable is as below.

```
<ngx-datatable #tableworkorder class="material" [rows]="this.gridWork"
                                [sortType]="'multi'" [columnMode]="'force'" [loadingIndicator]="loadingIndicator"
                                [headerHeight]="50" [footerHeight]="50" [rowHeight]="'auto'" [scrollbarH]="true"
                                [limit]="this.pageSize" [externalPaging]="true" [count]="this.itemCount"
                                (activate)="onActivate($event)" [offset]="this.pageNumber"
                                (page)="workPagination($event)" (resize)="onColumnResize($event)" (sort)="onSortGrid($event)">

</ngx-datatable>
```

If I sort this table I need to store this sort value and when coming from another page, I need to sort the table based on the saved sorted criteria.
how can I store also sort this table dynamically?

Comment: You can use the `[sorts]` input property. https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/src/app/sorting/sorting-default.component.ts#L27

Comment: @JasonWhite I need to set this sort property from typescript, because I need to save this sort and when coming from another page, I need to set this sort.

Comment: The `(sort)` binding will emit the current sorts on the table.  When you get a new value, store those sorts somewhere where they can be restored (ex a service).  When the component loads pull the previous sorts from that service and use the `[sorts]` property to restore the sorts.  The `[sorts]` binding will accept a property from your ts file.

Comment: Here is a rough stackblitz example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxdatatable-sort-test-1q9asa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata%2Fdata.component.ts

Comment: @JasonWhite your answer works,
[sorts]="getSortDetails()"
getSortDetails() {
        if (this.sortdetails) {
            return JSON.parse(this.sortdetails);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    onSortGrid(event) {
        this.sortdetails = JSON.stringify(event.sorts);
    }